# Chrome extension content script on https page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm going to hack out a chrome extension this weekend that adds keyboard shortcuts to a site I use all the time. It's showing when I go to that site's home page, but after I login and am in the admin area (where it uses https), my content script won't run.

```
{
  "name"            : "Keyboard Shortcuts",
  "version"         : "1.0",
  "description"     : "Adds keyboard shortcuts to this great site.",
  "permissions"     : ["https://SITENAME.com/", "http://SITENAME.com", "https://SITENAME.com/*", "http://SITENAME.com/*"],
  "content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches": ["https://SITENAME.com/*", "http://SITENAME.com/*", "*://SITENAME.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js", "hotkeys.js", "script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see my `manifest.json` file above. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. To debug you could try to use <all_urls> and see if that helps, also how are you checking that the script runs? Look with devtools or add an alert to the beginning of your content script.

Comment: Hey Boris, I'm using an alert to make sure it runs. On the regular page (not https), it alerts as expected, but not on the protected page.

Comment: In general, it works on HTTPs too.

Comment: I fixed it. I needed to have the 'www' in there as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by adding a 'www' to the URL.